# Как удалить (отключить) breadcrumbs от woocoomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs, yoast

Купили премиум Yoast и хочу использовать breadcrumbs от них. Но не как не получается отключить breadcrumbs от woocoomerce. Может кто-то уже пробовал что-то подобное делать?

Comment: Скрой их через css. Я так делал с неугодными элементами на wp. Они много не весят, так что потери допустимы

Comment: спасибо так и сделал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю какая у вас версия, но в своём время работало это. В function.php прописать:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
```

Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , не сработало , чёрт с ним ) скрыл через css